# CSS - Can you add space between images inside the same class?

Tags: css

So without creating more classes in the css, can you have say for example 3 images in the same class, and give them a percentage of space in-between them?

Or is it only possible to do this, by separating them using margin or padding?

Many thanks.

Comment: what do you exactly want?

Comment: Yes it is possible ... but how your code looks like ? which is the exact desired output ?  what have you tried?

Comment: Okay . So I have a 3 phone graphics on the same line which are each made of 3 layers. 1 - the template, 2. the content, 3 a black cover. At the moment when you hover over the black layer disappears, giving the effect of turning on. The issue with the current set up, is that they are also links, and the links are too close too each other as the correct positioning is achieved by using pngs with equal transparent spacing on each side. So basically I have 3 classes which each contain 3 images (1layer). I want to keep the classes, but just get the positioning right, but adding space to the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<!--this would normally contain images -->
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.image:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.myClass img{ 
    float:left; 
    width: 30%; 
    margin:0 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use selectors like not selecting the first child and give margin or padding whichever  you like

```
.image:not(:first-child){
    margin-right:10px
}
```